# Call multiple values outside while statement

Tags: php, mysql

```
   $searchquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM regform_admin WHERE status = 'Approved' AND month LIKE '%".$checkmonth."%' AND day LIKE '%".$checkday."%' AND year LIKE '%".$checkyear."%' OR month2 LIKE '%".$checkmonth."%' AND day2 LIKE '%".$checkday."%' AND year2 LIKE '%".$checkyear."%' OR betday LIKE '%".$checkday."%'");
            while($fetchres = mysql_fetch_array($searchquery)) { 
            $vehicles = $fetchres['vehicles']; 
            echo "<b>$vehicles</b><br>";
                    }

include "vehicledbconnect.php";
$searchquery2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicletbl WHERE vehicle NOT LIKE '%".$vehicles."%'");

    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($searchquery2)) {
    $v = $fetch['vehicle']; 
    $vehed = $fetch['vehed']; $vehcap = $fetch['vehcap']; $vehyr = $fetch['vehyr']; 
    $type = $fetch['type']; 
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class=light><input type = 'checkbox' name='chk[]'></td>";
        echo "<td class=light>$v</td>";
        echo "<td class=light>$type</td>";
        echo "<td class=light>$vehyr</td>";
        echo "<td class=light>$vehed</td>";
        echo "<td class=light>$vehcap</td>";
        echo "<td class=light>$vehcolor</td>";
        echo "</tr>";   
        echo "$array";
            }
```

Is it possible to echo all values inside the while statement from $searchquery inside $searchquery2?

For example the values of $searchquery is:

```
vehicle1
vehicle2
vehicle3
```

Now I'm going to echo all of it inside $searchquery2, is it possible? I try to echo $vehicles (from $searchquery) inside $searchquery2 but it only echoes the last value (example. vehicle3) because I know it is not inside the while statement of $searchquery.

Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Build a loop in loop.

Try this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM regform_admin WHERE...")
while(...)
{
   $vehicles = $fetchres['vehicles'];
   echo "<b>$vehicles</b><br>";

   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicletbl WHERE vehicle NOT LIKE '%".$vehicles."%'");
   while(...)
   {
       echo ...
   }

}
```

Comment: i already did this one but it doesn't give me the exact output that I wanted.

Comment: What was the problem? How the result should look like?

Comment: if I place $searchquery2 inside while loop of $searchquery, it multiplies the values of $searchquery2 depending on how many the result of $searchquery since it is inside $searchquery's while loop.

Comment: Please post the result of query1 and query2. Also a example of the list you want that it should look like. So it's very difficult for us.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `echo`ing inside the while loop, try buffering the output to a variable instead:

```
$ob = '';
while($fetchres = mysql_fetch_array($searchquery)) 
    $ob .= '<b>' . $fetchres['vehicles'] . '</b><br>';
echo($ob);
```

During your second while loop, `$ob` is still alive and you can echo it out just as easily.  Here I'm storing it as a string, but you can store the values as an array also if you need more granular access to the elements.

**Update**

If you want to store them into an array, try it this way:

```
$ob = array();
while($fetchres = mysql_fetch_array($searchquery)) 
    $ob[] = $fetchres['vehicle'];  // This pushes the current vehicle onto the end of the array
```

After this loop, you just have the string for each vehicle in the array, and none of the formatting.  You can add that in when you output the elements.  Iterate over your array with `foreach`:

```
foreach($ob as $k => $v) {
    // Inside this loop, $k is the key, or index, and $v is the value.
    // You can change the names of these variables by modifying the line above, e.g. 
    // foreach($ob as $foo => $bar)  <-- $foo = key/index, $bar = value
}
```

Comment: With this one I can echo out all of $ob from while($fetchres = mysql_fetch_array($searchquery)) inside while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($searchquery2))?

Comment: Sure, why not?  `$ob` will live as long as your script lives or until you explicitly `unset()` it.

Comment: What if I put all the values of $fetchres['vehicles'] into an array, can it be like "$ob .= '<b>' . array($fetchres['vehicles']) . '</b><br>';" ??
is it possible?

Comment: What will I echo inside the foreach? inside the foreach how can I echo out the values from $searchquery?

Comment: Inside the foreach, `$v` will be the value you will want to echo.